# Web3.js >> w3.eth.sendSignedTransaction the txn is submitted but not succesful

Tags: node.js, blockchain, ethereum, web3js

Description::

I've a signed txn and when I submit it using w3.eth.sendSignedTransaction , I see the following logs in my Geth log file

Geth logs are as follows:

```
INFO [05-24|12:01:44] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0xd6ad180c709ce93f5884070f28488925e9b944a24fc6ab737c79d8e66dfd9dca recipient=0xF06c0a4A9fafddA7b8B25F986e1C0dfEC62e1E84
```

I obtain the txn hash as shown above but now when I try to search my txn using the hash , following is what I get >> 
[image]

My question is :: Why the block hash is >> 0x0000 . . . . . ?

What could be wrong here ?

The code which is use to send this txn is as follows >>

```
w3.eth.sendSignedTransaction( data ).once( 'transactionHash', (hash) => {
    console.log(hash)
  }).on('receipt', (receipt) => {
    console.log('receipt');
  }).on('confirmation', (confirmationNumber, receipt) => {
    console.log('confirmation');
  }).on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  }).then( (receipt) => {
    console.log('finally got the receipt!');
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log('err');
  })
```

Comment: It looks like the transaction wasn’t mined yet. Did you get receipt/confirmation debug output and check the block hash after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.

This problem comes when our nonce is not one higher than the count of transactions from the account. 
Check whether the following equation is true in your case >>

```
NONCE = count_of_transactions_from_account + 1
```

Hope that helps!!!